# Generate all setXXX calls of a POJO in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jpa

Im currently doing a lot of testing with JPA entities, where i have to keep calling the setter methods on the entity that looks something like this :

```
myEntity.setXXX(value);
myEntity.setYYY(value);
myEntity.setZZZ(value);
```

Is there any magic shortcut or menu in eclipse IDE to generate all the setter-method-calls that starts with "set", like those displayed in the ctrl-space (auto completion) popup (i think the inherited methods from Object are not being shown at popup) ?

So im imagining something like :

1. i type myEntity.set
2. and myEntity.set* are generated right away

Im a lazy programmer and currently using Eclipse Helios IDE.

Thank you !

---

### Edit

Im not looking for source -> generate getter and setter, because that would helps me in generating the methods itself. Generating the `method calls` is what i want to achieve.

Comment: In re: your comment on my answer (which I deleted since it missed the question entirely, and I don't know of an answer to it): yes, you're just being lazy :)

Comment: @Matt Ball: Thanks, im flattered. Haha.

Comment: I was looking for the very same short cut ... Haha

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I have found the answer (I was always searching for this thing)...

The easiest way is to expand the class members in the "Package Explorer", sort them by name, multi-select all the setters, and then you have in the clipboard all the method names...

;-)

Comment: This is a really great idea and has saved a lot of time as I have to pass values into 238 set methods of a class.

Comment: And then you can use "Toggle Block Selection Mode" to prefix the setters with your instance name and add the ';' at the end of the lines.

Comment: if you want to have the order as in code, just deselect the ordering, after your multiselection is made

Comment: Use "Java" perspective rather than "Java EE", If you did not see class members listed

Comment: It's funny - I've wanted this for so long and usually end up using regex on the entire class to get it.  I stumbled onto this almost entirely by mistake, and you've already saved me about 5 minutes writing this blasted unit test.  Thank you!

Comment: It's awesome, I was looking for something to save myself from manually writing this object mapper. This trick works like charm ;)

Answer (score 3):

I like @Oscar's answer. It does lead to some cleanup though.

When I paste from the clipboard, I get something that looks like this:

```
setOne(int)  
setTwo(String)
```

In order to clean this up, I first add semicolons with this search/replace regexp:

```
search = (.)$
replace = \1;
```

Then I add the getter calls (assuming incoming data object is named "data"):

```
search = s(et.*)\(.*  
replace = s\1(data.g\1());
```

This doesn't handle multiple arguments in a method call...

Comment: That's very helpful! Just wondering where I can find out more about regexp  that can be used in Eclipse? I want to just strip away the value in between the ( and ); for example setTwo(String) to just setTwo()?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the outline at right side. There you can sort alphabetically or by declaration order using the toolbar button of the view.

[image]

and then you can filter out non required this.

[image]

[image]

From here also you can copy..all setter functions or getters functions names...

Answer (score 0):

There is eclipse plugin to do that. The name of the plugin is **

> FastCode

**. There are so many templates. Among those there is template to generate code for create object of the class and all setters method.

Answer (score -1):

`Source --> Generate Getters and Setters...`

You can also get at it via the Quick Fix command (`Ctrl+1`) when the cursor is on a property.

---

*EDIT*

If you are simply looking for a faster way to copy properties from one object to another I suggest that you look at using reflection. I think this path would be much easier long term then generating the same-looking code over-and-over.

[Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/) can take away some of the pain in writing pure reflection code. For example, [`copyProperties`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) takes a destination bean and either another bean or a Map as the source.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of using Common BeanUtils framework. But my intention is not to copy properties, but just to help me ease my work when doing testing that involves creating a new pojo, call the setter methods (perhaps like 10 setter methods), and to avoid missing calling some setter methods, i was looking for something to help generate the setter method calls in my editor. But im now very skeptic that this can be achieved :-)

Comment: @Albert Kam Agreed. FWIW, the naming of `copyProperties` is bit misleading -- it actually uses getters/setters to copy the property values (so the private field names themselves don't need to match between POJOs).